# Finding Max/Min of interpolated function and average value above/below the x axis

Tags: interpolation, maximum, averages

I have the below code used to create an interpolation function that will plot the difference between two interpolated functions (to compare between different periods of time).

However, I would like to find the max and minimum values within specific ranges (for this data between 4 and 23 on the x-axis).

I would also like some sort of average negative and positive value so I can find the average positive and negative change between the two data sets. I have been unsuccessful in finding examples of what I need online (or it is possible I haven't been able to understand them fully in how I can implement it with my own data)

The max min and averages are for  `DamOne1u2119` at the end of the code

```
DamOne1u2021={{-3., 52.584}, {-2., 52.584}, {-1., 52.584}, {0., 52.584}, {0.690359,
   52.129}, {1.35808, 51.935}, {2.15814, 51.785}, {2.83443, 
  51.765}, {3.39709, 51.703}, {3.81911, 51.45}, {4.31593, 
  51.458}, {4.91879, 50.931}, {5.48303, 50.638}, {6.05773, 
  50.506}, {7.40077, 49.892}, {7.66482, 49.873}, {8.36334, 
  49.792}, {8.78798, 49.792}, {9.38703, 49.887}, {9.79445, 
  49.912}, {10.3076, 49.967}, {10.8794, 49.971}, {11.2876, 
  50.086}, {11.801, 50.108}, {12.5217, 50.166}, {13.0028, 
  50.204}, {13.4898, 50.211}, {14.0177, 50.281}, {14.6184, 
  50.303}, {15.0467, 50.306}, {15.7232, 50.349}, {16.0804, 
  50.389}, {16.7198, 50.437}, {17.3869, 50.424}, {17.7724, 
  50.377}, {18.1859, 50.381}, {18.8983, 50.345}, {19.193, 
  50.289}, {21.36, 50.87}, {21.7722, 51.061}, {21.8349, 
  51.078}, {22.384, 51.351}, {22.8442, 51.574}, {23.3637, 
  51.866}, {24., 51.866}, {25., 51.866}, {26., 51.866}};
DamOne1u2019={{26., 52.143}, {25., 52.143}, {24., 52.143}, {23.3859, 
  52.143}, {23.1698, 51.942}, {21.4912, 51.068}, {21.0132, 
  50.936}, {20.4527, 50.861}, {19.0339, 50.846}, {18.3098, 
  50.8}, {17.8306, 50.793}, {17.4658, 50.762}, {17.0203, 
  50.722}, {16.4767, 50.717}, {15.98, 50.732}, {15.4513, 
  50.756}, {14.9287, 50.731}, {14.5165, 50.699}, {13.9742, 
  50.742}, {13.4617, 50.732}, {12.9475, 50.715}, {12.4889, 
  50.709}, {12.0645, 50.681}, {11.5034, 50.651}, {11.0292, 
  50.631}, {10.4117, 50.637}, {9.95895, 50.625}, {9.49877, 
  50.552}, {8.9786, 50.536}, {8.50658, 50.518}, {8.05728, 
  50.454}, {7.51495, 50.422}, {7.05679, 50.455}, {6.55668, 
  50.519}, {6.01821, 50.547}, {5.60583, 50.617}, {5.44458, 
  50.632}, {5.12869, 51.166}, {4.74713, 50.97}, {3.94958, 
  51.495}, {2.66635, 51.909}, {2.20125, 51.93}, {1.75397, 
  51.898}, {1.24684, 52.044}, {0.932995, 52.128}, {0.372399, 
  52.39}, {-0.109343, 52.729}, {-0.565013, 52.883}, {-1.04139, 
  53.041}, {-2., 53.041}, {-3., 53.041}, {-4., 53.041}};
SpDamOne1u2021 = 
 Interpolation[DamOne1u2021, Method -> "Spline", 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3];
SpDamOne1u2019 = 
 Interpolation[DamOne1u2019, Method -> "Spline", 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3];
DamOne1u2119 = SpDamOne1u2021[x] - SpDamOne1u2019[x]
```

Comment: Use `FindMinimum[{SpDamOne1u2021[x] - SpDamOne1u2019[x], 4 <= x <= 23}, {x,
   9}]` with out `{-0.746626, {x -> 8.68487}}`, and `FindMaximum[{SpDamOne1u2021[x] - SpDamOne1u2019[x], 4 <= x <= 23}, {x, 4.5}]` with out `{0.569714, {x -> 4.42633}}`

Comment: @AlexTrounev May I ask what the {x,    9} and {x,    4.5} do?

Comment: They are local definitions where to search. But if you don't know and prefer Automatic choice, then it could be better to compute global min/max on the mesh defined on `4<=x<=23` with using `MinimalBy, MaximalBy`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev So by local definition what does that entail exactly? Does it just search in the rough area of the number or does it not look any higher than that value? And how might I use `MinimalBy, MaximalBy`? I have had a look at the function but am a bit confused by it

Comment: First we prepare `xgrid = Range[4, 23, 10^-3]; lst = Table[{x, SpDamOne1u2021[x] - SpDamOne1u2019[x]}, {x, xgrid}];`. Then we use  `MinimalBy[lst, Last] // N` with out `{{8.685, -0.746626}}` , and `MaximalBy[lst, Last] // N` with out  `{{4.426, 0.569713}}`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev That's perfect, I think it actually makes the code easier than the other method for repeatability with different data. Just to try and get a better understanding of the code for the future, may I ask what the `10^-3` does in this context and whether it might need to change to a different value with other data?

Comment: This is a typical error of your model. So you can reduce or increase this parameter regarding to accuracy of your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

DamOne1u2021 = {{-3., 52.584}, {-2., 52.584}, {-1., 52.584}, {0., 
    52.584}, {0.690359, 52.129}, {1.35808, 51.935}, {2.15814, 
    51.785}, {2.83443, 51.765}, {3.39709, 51.703}, {3.81911, 51.45}, {4.31593,
     51.458}, {4.91879, 50.931}, {5.48303, 50.638}, {6.05773, 
    50.506}, {7.40077, 49.892}, {7.66482, 49.873}, {8.36334, 
    49.792}, {8.78798, 49.792}, {9.38703, 49.887}, {9.79445, 
    49.912}, {10.3076, 49.967}, {10.8794, 49.971}, {11.2876, 50.086}, {11.801,
     50.108}, {12.5217, 50.166}, {13.0028, 50.204}, {13.4898, 
    50.211}, {14.0177, 50.281}, {14.6184, 50.303}, {15.0467, 
    50.306}, {15.7232, 50.349}, {16.0804, 50.389}, {16.7198, 
    50.437}, {17.3869, 50.424}, {17.7724, 50.377}, {18.1859, 
    50.381}, {18.8983, 50.345}, {19.193, 50.289}, {21.36, 50.87}, {21.7722, 
    51.061}, {21.8349, 51.078}, {22.384, 51.351}, {22.8442, 51.574}, {23.3637,
     51.866}, {24., 51.866}, {25., 51.866}, {26., 51.866}};
DamOne1u2019 = {{26., 52.143}, {25., 52.143}, {24., 52.143}, {23.3859, 
    52.143}, {23.1698, 51.942}, {21.4912, 51.068}, {21.0132, 
    50.936}, {20.4527, 50.861}, {19.0339, 50.846}, {18.3098, 50.8}, {17.8306, 
    50.793}, {17.4658, 50.762}, {17.0203, 50.722}, {16.4767, 50.717}, {15.98, 
    50.732}, {15.4513, 50.756}, {14.9287, 50.731}, {14.5165, 
    50.699}, {13.9742, 50.742}, {13.4617, 50.732}, {12.9475, 
    50.715}, {12.4889, 50.709}, {12.0645, 50.681}, {11.5034, 
    50.651}, {11.0292, 50.631}, {10.4117, 50.637}, {9.95895, 
    50.625}, {9.49877, 50.552}, {8.9786, 50.536}, {8.50658, 50.518}, {8.05728,
     50.454}, {7.51495, 50.422}, {7.05679, 50.455}, {6.55668, 
    50.519}, {6.01821, 50.547}, {5.60583, 50.617}, {5.44458, 
    50.632}, {5.12869, 51.166}, {4.74713, 50.97}, {3.94958, 51.495}, {2.66635,
     51.909}, {2.20125, 51.93}, {1.75397, 51.898}, {1.24684, 
    52.044}, {0.932995, 52.128}, {0.372399, 52.39}, {-0.109343, 
    52.729}, {-0.565013, 52.883}, {-1.04139, 53.041}, {-2., 53.041}, {-3., 
    53.041}, {-4., 53.041}};
SpDamOne1u2021 = 
  Interpolation[DamOne1u2021, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
SpDamOne1u2019 = 
  Interpolation[DamOne1u2019, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
DamOne1u2119[x_?NumericQ] := SpDamOne1u2021[x] - SpDamOne1u2019[x]
```

Plotting,

```
Legended[
 ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
  Plot[{SpDamOne1u2021[x], SpDamOne1u2019[x]}, {x, -3, 26},
   Frame -> True],
  Plot[DamOne1u2119[x], {x, -4, 26},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Red,
   PlotStyle -> Red],
  "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[{ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2], Red},
   {"SpDamOne1u2021", "SpDamOne1u2019", "DamOne1u2119"}],
  {0.6, 0.75}]]
```

[image]

Min, Max, and average values in the interval `{4, 23}`

```
{min2019, max2019} = #[{SpDamOne1u2019[x], 4 <= x <= 23}, x] & /@ 
  {MinValue, MaxValue}

(* {50.4218, 51.7481} *)

avg2019 = NIntegrate[SpDamOne1u2019[x], {x, 4, 23}]/(23 - 4)

(* 50.7602 *)

{min2021, max2021} = #[{SpDamOne1u2021[x], 4 <= x <= 23}, x] & /@
  {MinValue, MaxValue}

(* {49.7823, 51.6661} *)

avg2021 = NIntegrate[SpDamOne1u2021[x], {x, 4, 23}]/(23 - 4)

(* 50.3677 *)

{mindif, maxdif} = #[{DamOne1u2119[x], 4 <= x <= 23}, x] & /@
  {MinValue, MaxValue}

{MinValue[{DamOne1u2119[x], 4 <= x <= 23}, x], 
 MaxValue[{DamOne1u2119[x], 4 <= x <= 23}, x]}

avgdif = NIntegrate[DamOne1u2119[x], {x, 4, 23}]/(23 - 4)

(* -0.392483 *)

avgdif - (avg2021 - avg2019)

(* -1.72071*10^-6 *)
```

The average positive difference in the interval {4, 23} is

```
NIntegrate[Boole[DamOne1u2119[x] > 0]*DamOne1u2119[x], {x, 4, 23},
  MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 50,
  Method -> {"MonteCarloRule", "Points" -> 200}]/
 NIntegrate[Boole[DamOne1u2119[x] > 0], {x, 4, 23},
  MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 50,
  Method -> {"MonteCarloRule", "Points" -> 200}]

(* 0.204013 *)
```

The average negative difference in the interval {4, 23} is

```
NIntegrate[Boole[DamOne1u2119[x] < 0]*DamOne1u2119[x], {x, 4, 23},
  MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 50,
  Method -> {"MonteCarloRule", "Points" -> 200}]/
 NIntegrate[Boole[DamOne1u2119[x] < 0], {x, 4, 23},
  MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 50,
  Method -> {"MonteCarloRule", "Points" -> 200}]

(* -0.451114 *)
```

Comment: When I try to use the average negative and average positive difference I just get back error messages. I am on Version 13 on a windows 11 64-bit computer. I have no plugins or add ons

Comment: It might be easier and actually better (not that I think about it) to just do the average y value in the range, rather than average positive and average negative y values.  I tried using this section of the code `avgdif = NIntegrate[DamOne1u2119[x], {x, 4, 23}]/(23 - 4)` but it is not giving me the output `1/19 NIntegrate[DamOne1u2119[x], {x, 4, 23}]`

Comment: "I just get back error messages" doesn't help us troubleshoot your problem. You need to tell us what the error messages are. If you are seeing `1/19 NIntegrate[DamOne1u2119[x], {x, 4, 23}]`, did you clear the old definition and use the revised definition? Use `DamOne1u2119[x_?NumericQ] := SpDamOne1u2021[x] - SpDamOne1u2019[x]`

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I cleared the older definition for the function and it is working as expected now